# Codeigniter after update 3.1.1 to 3.1.2 error batch_update

Tags: php, codeigniter

Since I run Codeigniter 3.1.1 no problem just several update I haven't check my slide Change position id and error on Codeigniter 3.1.2

```
$data = [
    ['sl_id' =>  49, 'sl_move' => 1],
    ['sl_id' => 48, 'sl_move' => 2]
];

// error this update_batch line : Undefined index: sl_id

if( ! $this->db->update_batch($this->table, $data, 'sl_id'))
{
    //FALSE
}
else
{
    //TRUE
}
```

SQl syntax that error show below:

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'THEN '49' WHEN `sl_id` = THEN '48' ELSE `sl_id` END, `sl_move` = CASE WHEN `sl' at line 2

UPDATE `tbl_slide` SET `sl_id` = CASE WHEN `sl_id` = THEN '49' WHEN `sl_id` = THEN '48' ELSE `sl_id` END, `sl_move` = CASE WHEN `sl_id` = THEN '1' WHEN `sl_id` = THEN '2' ELSE `sl_move` END WHERE `sl_id` IN(,)

Filename: C:/wamp/www/CodeIgniter_Project/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump( $this->table );`?

Comment: @Blinkydamo Value in $data array is what i got from var_dump, if i restore back to 3.1.1 this work but in 3.1.2 it give this error

Comment: It appears that a fix for an `update_batch` bug in v3.1.1 resulted in a new bug which you are experiencing. At the moment, It is an [open issue](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/4892) on CI github. You may want to revert back to 3.1.1 until this is addressed.